# Does the pumping lemma for context-free languages really require accepting a string with zero levels of nesting?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

In the pumping lemma conditions for context-free grammar we have that the string can be divided into $uv^{i}xy^{i}z$, but in the case of $i = 0$, why does it still belong to the language?, is it possible to have an example with a string?
Should it be $i = 1$ is one repetition and for $i = 0$?

In the case $i = 0$ the word $w = uxz$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer by Hendrik Jan is correct. Here is a concrete example. Consider a CFG $G$ with the following rules $S \to aSb|\epsilon$. It is not hard to see that $L(G) = \{a^n b^n: n\geq 0\}$, and that for example, $p = 4$ is a pumping constant for $L(G)$. Indeed, every word $d$ in $L(G)$ of length at least $4$, is of the form $d = a^k \cdot a \cdot \epsilon \cdot b \cdot b^k$, where $k\geq 1$. Hence, we can write $d$ as $d = uvxyz$, where $ u = a^k, v = a $, $x =\epsilon, y = b$, and $z=b^k$. Clearly, $|vxy| =2 \leq p$. Also,
it is easy to verify that for all $i\geq 0$, the word $uv^ix y^i z$ is in $L(G)$. Indeed, by pumping $v$ and $y$ $i$ times, we add/remove the same number of $a$'s and $b$'s in the appropriate places.

Now you can consider the word $u = a^2b^2 \in L(G)$ of length at least $4$, and write it as $uv  x  y z$, where $u = v = a, x = \epsilon, \text{and }y =z =b$. Then, you can pump down with $i = 0$ and get the word $u\cdot v^0 x y^0 z = a \cdot \epsilon^3 \cdot b = ab \in L(G)$.

Comment: Thank you for the example, it is now clearer

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I also write to you this other doubt of mine: 
when we prove the theorem, we say that p = k+1, where k is the cardinality of the variables. So the tree will have depth k+1 and $|w| >= 2^{k+1}$. 
But in the case of i = 0 where we do not repeat the variable and have only A, then the variables are k, but how is this possible if we have considered k+1 as the minimum?

Comment: Note that my example is simple in the sense that I managed to prove that the language satisfies the conditions of the pumping lemma easily. When we prove the theorem, we can assume w.l.o.g that the CFG is in CNF form. Then, a parsing tree of a word that the grammar generates is a full binary tree. So $p = 2^{k+1}$, and $|w| \geq p$. Since we assume CNF form, $A\neq S$ is an internal variable that repeats. Regarding your doubts. $k+1$ is the length from root to leaf that we need to have so that we repeat a variable, and then we can pump up or down. We don't care which tree we get after pumping.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that when we prove that $|vy| > 0 $, then absurdly consider $ v = y = ε $ we will have a tree with no repetition of a variable and this results in a tree smaller than the minimum considered above (with at least 1 repetition of the variable). 

Now why in the case of i = 0 where v and y are eliminated does the tree we obtain belong to the language and in the case above it does not?

Comment: After pumping down, you get a parsing tree for some word in the language of the grammar. Yet, that smaller tree need not repeat a variable. No one claimed that the tree that repeats a variable is the smallest parsing tree that the grammar induces -- Its just a tree that we can pump parts of it up or down. Does this answer your doubts?

Answer (score 3):

If the string generated by the grammar is long enough then somewhere in the derivation tree we will find a path with a repeated variable. Below that is $A$. This induces the devision $vwxyz$ of the generated string into substrings, following the subtrees in the derivation.

Using the rules of the grammar we can play with the derivations $S\Rightarrow^* vAz$ (outer part of the tree), $A \Rightarrow^* wAy 
$ (middle part, which can be repeated) and $A \Rightarrow^* x$ (under the lowest $A$). In that way we find derivations for all strings $vw^ixy^iz$, including the case $i=0$, where we indeed obtain $vxz$.

[image: derivation tree and pumping]

Sorry my symbols are a little off. I reused an old picture.

Comment: When we prove the theorem, we say that p = k+1, where k is the cardinality of the variables. So the tree will have depth $k+1$ and $|w| >= 2^{k+1}$. 
But in the case of $i = 0$ where we do not repeat the variable and have only A, then the variables are k, but how is this possible if we have considered $k+1$ as the minimum?